# Dropwizard not logging to file

Tags: dropwizard

I have logging configured in my dropwizard yml file to log to a file and not to the console, however some logs are still being logged to the console.

service.yml

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      threshold: DEBUG
      logFormat: "%-6level [%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
      currentLogFilename: /tmp/application.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /tmp/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
      archivedFileCount: 7
      timeZone: UTC
```

When I execute I get my service logs in my log file but i get request logs on the console and not in the log file

```
127.0.0.1 -  -  [11/Nov/2015:22:31:52 +0000] "GET /api/v1/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/7.15.3 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8w" 1
```

Im using Dropwizard 0.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to configure an appender for request logs. The default appender is console.

Reference: https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.7.1/docs/manual/configuration.html#request-log